# Program to start on EC2 instance boot.

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a program that I run on amazon EC2 and I would like to set it up in a way so that when I boot a new EC2 instance it starts the program and sets itself up without any input from me.

How could i do this?

The program is a java .jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are booting the machine from an AMI with java installed and the program in a particular directory, you can have the command to start the program (jar -jar ... ) in somefile like /etc/rc.local.

Answer (score 1):

If, by chance, it is Windows, you could also run a batch file on system startup:

```
1. Run REGEDT32.EXE.
2. Modify the following value within HKEY_CURRENT_USER:

   Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ParseAutoexec

   1 = autoexec.bat is parsed
   0 = autoexec.bat is not parsed
```